# CORDOVA / phonegap NFC - reading and writing tag

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, nfc, phonegap

I want to read the NFC card with Phonegap, but the code is not working.
The code is reading NFC card for public transport or fitness cards (and works perfectly), but it is not reading bank cards.
When I try to read all bank cards it seems that NFC is not reading it at all. I get a white screen with text: "Tag is empty or phone is not aligned". It seams that app not recognize bank cards.

> ```
>  var app = {
>     initialize: function() {
>     this.bindEvents();
>     },
>     bindEvents: function() {
>     document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
>     },
>        onDeviceReady: function() {
>             app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
>             var success = function() {
>                 console.log("Listening for formatable NFC tags");
>             };
>             var failure = function(reason) {
>                 console.log("Error adding NFC listener " + reason);
>             };
>       
>     
>             nfc.addNdefFormatableListener(app.onNfc, success, failure);
>         },
>         onNfc: function(nfcEvent) {
>           
>           // display the tag as JSON
>         alert(JSON.stringify(nfcEvent.tag));
>     
>             var success = function() {
>                 alert("Wrote data to tag");
>             };
>             var failure = function(reason) {
>                 alert("NFC write failed " + reason);
>             };
>     
>             var message = [
>                 ndef.uriRecord("http://www.amazon.com/dp/1457187094")
>             ];
>     
>             nfc.write(message, success, failure);
>     
>         },
>       
>       
>     // Update DOM on a Received Event
>     receivedEvent: function(id) {
>         var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
>         var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
>         var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
>     
>         listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
>         receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
>     
>         console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
>     }
>     };
>     
>     app.initialize();
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Ndef is only one of the many data formats that are used on NFC cards.

Bank cards don't conform to the Ndef standard but another standard instead, thus when you try and read a Ndef message from a card that does not have a Ndef message on it and cannot store an Ndef message, it says it is empty of Ndef messages.

Comment: I try with different ones, but still the same problem. Could it be something else?

Comment: I would update the question with the more details of what you tried with the exact make and model of any additional cards your tried.

Comment: I try a few bank cards and they are not working. 
Other cards that are working are card for public transport and fitness loyalty card (for entering the gym). These two work perfectly. 
I need to scan bank cards to read info from it that users do not need write information in app by themself.

Comment: As I said Bank cards do not conform to the Ndef standard so forget about trying to read data of that standard from a bank card. Most Banks cards conform to the low level NFC Type 4 standard, so you should look at reading at the low level a Type 4 Card, then there are a number of AID's (Application ID's) you need to understand and use to read bank cards. You should ask a new question targeting what you actually want to do. You are never be able to write to banks cards so forgot about that as well.